# Add text after label in a Manipulate graphic

Tags: manipulate, text

I can add the value of a slider to the right of it using the Appearance-->Labelled option, but what if I want to add text after the automatic label. How can I do that?

Normally I want to do this to show the units of the value. For example, if the slider label is "4.7", I might want it to read "4.7 meters".

Answer (score 9):

There are many ways to do this. The most basic is to use `Control`, added few versions earlier just for this purpose. Here is an example. `Control` can be inserted inside `Row` or `Column` or `Grid` for example

```
Manipulate[x,
 Row[{Control[{{x, 1, "x="}, 0, 1, .1}],
   Spacer[5],
   Dynamic[x],
   Spacer[2],
   "meters"}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Quantity` to specify the initial value and domain of a control:

```
Manipulate[x, {{x, Quantity[1, "Meters"], "x ="},
               Quantity[Range[0, 1, .1], "Meters"],
               ControlType -> Manipulator , 
               Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Few more alternatives:

```
Manipulate[Quantity[x, "Meters"], 
 Row[{Control[{{x, 1, "x="}, 0, 1, .1}], Spacer[5], Dynamic@Quantity[x, "Meters"]}]]

Manipulate[Quantity[x, "Meters"],
 Labeled[Control[{{x, 1, "x="}, 0, 1, .1}], Dynamic@Quantity[x, "Meters"], Right]]
```

Comment: This looks good, but what if the text is not a quantity? How can I place arbitrary text instead of "Meters"?

Comment: @philmcole, nasser's and eldo's answers should work for that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
Framed[
 Row[{
   "Interval",
   IntervalSlider[Dynamic[m], {0, 3, 0.1}, Appearance -> "Markers"],
   Dynamic[m],
   " meters"}],
 Background -> GrayLevel@0.9,
 FrameMargins -> 15]
```

[image]

Thanks to **alancalvitty**'s comment: Much nicer is:

```
Framed[
 Row[{
   "Interval",
   IntervalSlider[
    Dynamic[m], {0, 3, 0.1},
    Appearance -> "Markers"],
   Dynamic[m], " meters"}],
 BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 14],
 RoundingRadius -> 10,
 Background -> GrayLevel @ 0.9,
 FrameMargins -> 15,
 FrameStyle -> GrayLevel @ 0.7]
```

[image]

Comment: Eldo, that's nice. Add these to `Framed`: `RoundingRadius -> 10, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 14]]`